# Siri extension file got deleted in embedded content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri

I added Siri Custom Intent Extension in my project, and I was able to execute the custom intents it was working fine, **but somehow the Myintent.appex file got deleted from the (Frameworks,Libraries and Embeded content) under General tab in target**

From then the custom Siri intent is not working, whenever I execute Siri shortcut command Siri is not responding and it directly opening the app itself.

***I tried to manually add the Myintent.appex file to (Frameworks,Libraries and Embeded content) under General tab in target, the project is not compiling and throws below compile error***

> Couldn't load Info dictionary for
> <DVTFilePath:0x7fb47bc72db0:'/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dqytyesirfltsnduzvpjdozsoxtp/Build/Products/StagingDebug-iphonesimulator/Appname.app/PlugIns/Myintent.appex

Its kind of weird, any suggestion would be really helpful